# Use $(Selector) without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am currently using something like this:

```
function Select(query)
{
    return query[0] === '#' ? document.querySelector(query) : document.querySelectorAll(query);
}
```

I have to use it like:

```
Select('#id').innerHTML = "content", or Select('.class')
```

Is there a way I can use $('#id) or $('.class') without jQuery?

Comment: Keep in mind that your current implementation is not like jQuery's `$(...)` because you return a single DOM element sometimes and an HTMLCollection object other times.

Comment: Are you really just asking how to use a different name for your function, or is there more depth to your question that I'm missing?

Comment: Also keep in mind that JQuery selectors return JQuery objects, not DOM elements. The DOM element in the result of a JQuery selector is the <result>[0], so you cannot use your renamed function interchangeably.

Comment: I was just looking to shorten Select, so instead of Select('#id'). I wanted to do $('#id); Thanks

Comment: Yeah, if you want a shorter name, then use a shorter name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `window.$=Select` or change name of function to `$`

This won't enhance any capabilities...just shorten the code when you use it

Comment: Yea, that's what I'm looking for. I'm just looking to shorten it. Thanks!